# 'Problem with SSL certificate' для Jmeter при записи TestScriptRecorder

Tags: jmeter

Помогите пожалуйста , что мне делать с данной ошибкой

> 2019-07-23 17:39:26,421 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [8912]  Problem with
>   SSL certificate for url  for 'fonts.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is
>   set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort:
>   recv failed

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ранее никогда не делал нагрузочное тестирование, а тут поставили задачу, и я никак не могу разобраться. 
При записи сценария с локального сервера, Jmeter его не видит.(на всех остальных вэб сайтах, всё ок)

Я так понял нужно сгенерировать и поставить ssl сертификат, вот только как это сделать?

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: нашёл и установил сертификат)))
Спасибо

Comment: Рад был помочь)